# Icon theme changed when enable dark mode

Tags: icon-themes

I changed the default icon theme from ubuntu to another theme. after i activate the dark mode feature, the icon theme returns to default. How do I keep my icon theme from changing when I activate the dark mode feature?

Comment: The same is happening to me, so I created an issue <https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/7433> that you can follow